# Pygame Button with rounded Corners, border_radius argument does not work

Tags: python, pygame, rounded-corners, rect

I am currently learning pygame. When programming rectangles with rounded corners I encountered a problem.

> pygame.draw.rect()
>   draw a rectangle
>   rect(surface, color, rect) -> Rect
>   rect(surface, color, rect, width=0, border_radius=0, border_radius=-1, border_top_left_radius=-1, border_top_right_radius=-1, border_bottom_left_radius=-1) -> Rect
>   Draws a rectangle on the given surface.
>
> border_radius (int) -- (optional) used for drawing rectangle with rounded corners. The supported range is [0, min(height, width) / 2], with 0 representing a rectangle without rounded corners.

This is the description of the official pygame documentation.

```
username_rect = pg.rect.Rect(screenwidth/2 - 1/8*screenwidth, screenheight*1/5, 1/4*screenwidth, username_title_render.get_height() + 10)
pg.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), username_rect,border_radius = 15)
```

Here the main part. But then I get this error message:

```
TypeError: 'border_radius' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I already tried to add a "width=2" argument but then it says that there are too many arguments. Unfortunately taking other numbers does not help either.
I am currently using pygame version 2.0.0.dev6 (SDL 2.0.10, python 3.8.1)

I would be very happy if you could help me, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I ran into this and had to do it myself already. Try the routines in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is for 2.0.0.dev7, and according to [this PR](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/1494), `border_radius` was added after 2.0.0.dev6, [GitHub reference](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/releases/tag/2.0.0.dev6), was released. So you're trying to use something that hasn't come out yet. You could try building from source and using the keyword (though stability is not a promise). Or you could try using a combination of rectangles and circles to achieve the effect.

Comment: Hey shynjax287! Thank you for your quick and helpful answer. You are totally right, I completely missed that. Unfortunately pygame 2.0.0.dev7 does not work yet, I will try to use circles at the corners.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this and had to do it myself already, I might as well share.

Try these, one draws rectangles with rounded corners and the other draws bordered rounded rectangles. They use anti-aliased circles to draw the corners because otherwise they look pretty jagged:

```
import pygame.gfxdraw

def draw_rounded_rect(surface, rect, color, corner_radius):
    ''' Draw a rectangle with rounded corners.
    Would prefer this: 
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect, border_radius=corner_radius)
    but this option is not yet supported in my version of pygame so do it ourselves.

    We use anti-aliased circles to make the corners smoother
    '''
    if rect.width < 2 * corner_radius or rect.height < 2 * corner_radius:
        raise ValueError(f"Both height (rect.height) and width (rect.width) must be > 2 * corner radius ({corner_radius})")

    # need to use anti aliasing circle drawing routines to smooth the corners
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(surface, rect.left+corner_radius, rect.top+corner_radius, corner_radius, color)
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(surface, rect.right-corner_radius-1, rect.top+corner_radius, corner_radius, color)
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(surface, rect.left+corner_radius, rect.bottom-corner_radius-1, corner_radius, color)
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(surface, rect.right-corner_radius-1, rect.bottom-corner_radius-1, corner_radius, color)

    pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(surface, rect.left+corner_radius, rect.top+corner_radius, corner_radius, color)
    pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(surface, rect.right-corner_radius-1, rect.top+corner_radius, corner_radius, color)
    pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(surface, rect.left+corner_radius, rect.bottom-corner_radius-1, corner_radius, color)
    pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(surface, rect.right-corner_radius-1, rect.bottom-corner_radius-1, corner_radius, color)

    rect_tmp = pygame.Rect(rect)

    rect_tmp.width -= 2 * corner_radius
    rect_tmp.center = rect.center
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect_tmp)

    rect_tmp.width = rect.width
    rect_tmp.height -= 2 * corner_radius
    rect_tmp.center = rect.center
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect_tmp)


def draw_bordered_rounded_rect(surface, rect, color, border_color, corner_radius, border_thickness):
    if corner_radius < 0:
        raise ValueError(f"border radius ({corner_radius}) must be >= 0")

    rect_tmp = pygame.Rect(rect)
    center = rect_tmp.center

    if border_thickness:
        if corner_radius <= 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, border_color, rect_tmp)
        else:
            draw_rounded_rect(surface, rect_tmp, border_color, corner_radius)

        rect_tmp.inflate_ip(-2*border_thickness, -2*border_thickness)
        inner_radius = corner_radius - border_thickness + 1
    else:
        inner_radius = corner_radius

    if inner_radius <= 0:
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect_tmp)
    else:
        draw_rounded_rect(surface, rect_tmp, color, inner_radius)
```